# ExceptionHandler works in a controller but not in separate class

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation

I have a controller in Spring Boot 3, which looks like this:

```java
@PostMapping("/login")
public ResponseEntity<Object> login(@Valid @RequestBody CustomUserDetails user) {
 ...
}
```

As you see, I am using `@Valid` because of annotations that I use, such as `@Size(min = 8)` or `@Email`. Now I want to send a message, if an entity was invalid. To do this, I am using this exception handler:

```java
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleValidationException(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
    Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();
    ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors().forEach(error -> errors.put(error.getField(), error.getDefaultMessage()));
    return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(errors);
}
```

This works fine, if that code is in my controller. This is the response that I get:

```xml
{
    "password": "password length should be at least 8 characters",
    "username": "username should be a valid email address"
}
```

But I need this code in more than 1 controller. So instead of that, I have just created another class.

```java
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ValidationExceptionHandler {
    /**
     * Validation Exception Handler
     * @param ex Exception
     * @return A response
     */
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleValidationException(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
        Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();
        ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors().forEach(error -> errors.put(error.getField(), error.getDefaultMessage()));
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(errors);
    }
}
```

But now it doesn't work. Instead, this is the response that I get:

```xml
{
    "type": "about:blank",
    "title": "Bad Request",
    "status": 400,
    "detail": "Invalid request content.",
    "instance": "/login"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

This is my folder structure:

```
com.example.my_app
  - auth
    - AuthController
    - AuthControllerAdvice
  - config
    - SecurityConfig
  - exception
    - ErrorResponse
    - RestExceptionHandler
    - ValidationExceptionHandler
```

Comment: Make sure the exception handler is in the same package as the controller(s), or a subpackage of the application main class.

Comment: @E-Riz isn't there another solution? I am using a package for each feature and each feature has its own controller. I have updated my question, so you see my folder structure.

Comment: Where is your application's "main" class, where you initialize the `SpringApplication` and context? What package?

Comment: @E-Riz the main class is located in the root package of the project, which is `com.example.my_app`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have several exception handlers (based on your folder structure), you might use the annotation `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)`. So try it that way:

```java
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ValidationExceptionHandler {
    /**
     * Validation Exception Handler
     * @param ex Exception
     * @return A response
     */
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleValidationException(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
        Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();
        ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors().forEach(error -> errors.put(error.getField(), error.getDefaultMessage()));
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(errors);
    }
}
```

By using this annotation, your exception handler gets the highest priority and will be executed first, before any other exception handlers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make following changes in your ControllerAdvice:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@ResponseBody
public class ControllerExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public ErrorMessage handleValidationException(MethodArgumentNotValidException 
    ex, WebRequest request) {
    ErrorMessage message = new ErrorMessage(...);
    return message;
   }
}
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: `@RestControllerAdvice` is just a combination of `@ControllerAdvice` and `@ResponseBody`, so this is basically equivalent to what the question has.

Comment: I tried that out. But still the same issue.

Comment: then it seems like your ControllerAdvice is not getting detected. Did you check startup logs to verify it is being created?

Comment: The ControllerAdvice gets detected! I know this, because I am using another ControllerAdvice with other exceptions. Other exceptions work but if I use `MethodArgumentNotValidException.class` in the same class, it doesn't work.